# It is possible to access a dynamic object of Excel UserForm1 from code of UserForm2? Not from code of a module

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "Class" Module whit declaration and events of my dynamics labels

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ClassLabel As MSForms.Label

Public Sub ClassLabel_Click() 
    If InStr(ClassLabel.Name, "LB_Label") Then
        Set CurrentLabel = ClassLabel   
        'Bla Bla Bla
    End If
End Sub
```

And I have created 15 dynamic labels, in the "FR_Runtime" frame of UserForm1, which I have saved in an array in the Controls_Init() Sub of a normal Module1 as follows

```
Option Explicit

Public gArrayClassLabel() As New Class
Public CurrentLabel As MSForms.Label

Public Sub Controls_Init()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim nRow As Integer
    Dim H As Integer
    Dim LB_Label As MSForms.Label        
    nRow = 15
    H = 30
    ReDim gArrayClassLabel(1 To nRow)        
    For Row = 1 To nRow
    Set LB_Label = UserForm1.FR_Runtime.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    With LB_Label
        .Name = "LB_Label" & Row
        .Caption = "    Label " & Row & ", 2"
        .Left = 100
        .Top = H
        .Width = 75
        .Height = 18
        .ForeColor = vbRed
        .BackColor = vbWindowBackground
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
        .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
    End With
    Set gArrayClassLabel(Row).ClassLabel = LB_Label    
    H = H + 30
Next Row
End Sub
```

From my UserForm1.FR_Runtime_Exit() event (or any other UserForm1, Module1 code), I have access to the fifth dynamic label as follows

```
Private Sub FR_Runtime_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Set glbCurrentLabel = gArrayClassLabel(5).ClassLabel
    With UserForm1.TextBox1
        .Text = Trim$(glbCurrentLabel.Caption)
        .Left = glbCurrentLabel.Left
        .Top = glbCurrentLabel.Top
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(glbCurrentLabel.Caption)
    End With
End Sub
```

From UserForm2, I can access to a label created at design time: `UserForm1.Label3.Caption = "This is an design time Label"`

Can I acces the gArrayClassLabel(5).ClassLabel from a Sub of The UserForm2? Not from Module1 code.

Comment: You should be able  to add in get/set type functions in the module1 code to allow access

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tragamor, I had not thought about the class modules properties. This is the new "Class" Module

```
Public WithEvents ClassLabel As MSForms.Label
Private sContent As String

'new Get property
Property Get Content() As String
    Content= sContent 
End Property

'new Let property
Property Let Content(NumLbl As String)
    sContent = gArrayClassLabel(NumLbl).ClassLabel.Caption
End Property

Public Sub ClassLabel_Click() 
    If InStr(ClassLabel.Name, "LB_Label") Then
        Set CurrentLabel = ClassLabel   
        'Bla Bla Bla
    End If
End Sub
```

And I can access the fifth dynamic label Caption from anywhere in the code as follows

```
Dim NumDynamicLabel As New Class
'I use Let Content property to obtain the fifth dynamic label Caption
NumDynamicLabel.Content = 5 
        
Dim CaptionDynamicLabel As String
'I use the Get Content Property to retrieve Caption of fifth dynamic label 
CaptionDynamicLabel = NumDynamicLabel.Content
```